# SignalR: Single hub call blows up on one server with a socket error

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Very odd thing happening.. I have a hub deployed to a few dev boxes and a QA box. All are runnin Windows 2008 R2 and IIS. Everything works on the dev machines. The QA box (hosted in amazon EC2 if it matters) fails on a single hub call and throws the below error in the browser console.

All our dev boxes return just fine from this same call.

```
SignalR: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) jquery.signalR.min.js:1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Groups' of undefined jquery.signalR.min.js:1
u.processMessages jquery.signalR.min.js:1
f.transports.serverSentEvents.start jquery.signalR.min.js:1
```

I've tried updating to SignalR 0.5.1 (was on 0.5.0), copying the DLLs directly from dev to QA to ensure same code, disabling the firewalls in case EC2 is doing something weird (same error via 127.0.0.1 so that's not it).. I'm lost.. What setting am I missing?

Comment: Can you file a bug on github with precise repro steps?

Comment: Issue 477 submitted -- thanks David!